# Converting a collection to Map by sorting it using java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, linkedhashmap

I have a list that I need to custom sort and then convert to a map with its Id vs. name map.

Here is my code:

```
Map<Long, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Building::getName)).forEach(b-> map.put(b.getId(), b.getName()));
```

I think this will do the job but I wonder if I can avoid creating `LinkedHashMap` here and use fancy functional programming to do the job in one line.

Comment: Use `toMap()` of `java.util.stream.Collectors`

Comment: Besides that using `collect` is preferable you should beware that `sorted(…).forEach(…)` is wrong (despite it sometimes works). What you really mean is `sorted(…).forEachOrdered(…)`…

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have `Collectors.toMap` for that purpose :

```
Map<Long, String> map = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Building::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Building::getId,Building::getName));
```

If you want to force the Map implementation that will be instantiated, use this :

```
Map<Long, String> map = 
    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Building::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Building::getId,
                                  Building::getName,
                                  (v1,v2)->v1,
                                  LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: toMap will convert this in HashMap right? which doesn't guarantee sorting?

Comment: @MohdAdnan The returned implementation is not guaranteed. You can force the implementation you wish by using the [4 parameter version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-). With the last parameter - the Supplier - you can specify which Map implementation will be instantiated.

Comment: Please note that, this implementation will omit the second entry for duplicate key.

Comment: @Masud I was assuming there are no duplicates in this use case. If there are, a groupingBy Collector may be more appropriate.

Comment: given that the map implementation determines sorting, is there any need for  the `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Building::getName))` line?

Comment: @Emanuel that depends on the chosen Map implementation.  In this example, LinkedHashMap is used, which keeps track of the insertion order of the keys. Therefore sorted is needed if you wish the keys to by inserted in the order imposed by the Comparator.

Comment: @Eran got it, sorting only makes sense if the map implementation iterates entries based on insertion order. For other map implementations sorting before insertion is irrelevant.