# How to replace HashMap with LinkedhashMap with streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, linkedhashmap, collectors

Could you please help me to sort my `Map`?

I have the following structure and I want to assemble apps under customers in a `LinkedHashMap` in a reversed order by value.

```
[{
  "CUSTOMER_1": {
    "APP_1": "1"
  },
  "CUSTOMER_2": {
    "APP_1": "2",
    "APP_3": "7",
    "APP_2": "3"
  }
}]
```

I already have a lambda that assembles the map:

```
 final Map<String, Map<String, Long>> organizationApps = taskHandles.stream().map(this::mapPayload)
            .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, of(HashMap::new,
                    (r, t) -> t.getValue().forEach((k, v) -> r.merge(k, v, Long::sum)),
                    (r1, r2) -> {
                        r2.forEach((v1, v2) -> r1.merge(v1, v2, Long::sum));
                        return r1;
                    }))
            );
```

What I need now is to replace `organizationApps` values that are represented by `HashMap` with a `LinkedHashMap` and put the values into `LinkedHashMap` in a proper order.

How can I do it in lambda?

UPD:

I can achieve the necessary output with the following piece of code:

```
    final Map<String, Map<String, Long>> organizationApps = taskHandles.stream().map(this::mapPayload)
            .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, of(HashMap::new,
                    (r, t) -> t.getValue().forEach((k, v) -> r.merge(k, v, Long::sum)),
                    (r1, r2) -> {
                        r2.forEach((v1, v2) -> r1.merge(v1, v2, Long::sum));
                        return r1;
                    }))
            );

    organizationApps.forEach((key, value) -> {
        final Map<String, Long> sorted = value.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));
        organizationApps.put(key, sorted);
    });
```

How can I do it in one lambda?

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721095/converting-a-collection-to-map-by-sorting-it-using-java-8-streams. The important part is that you need to sort your stream appropriately before collecting.

Comment: Hi Ryan! I think I need to sort it after I assemble the map because initially I can have 2 lists with maps with duplicated keys and I merge the maps by summing the values

Comment: I have following question: Why do you need to do this in one lambda? Even if this possible - you will probably have really big and ugly peace of code. And I have hard times understanding what's going on in you code already. IMHO lambdas are not always best solution for this kind of problems. As stated [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips) - **lambdas should be an expression, not a narrative. Despite its concise syntax, lambdas should precisely express the functionality they provide.**

Comment: 1) Because I want to look at the result and compare it with the following 2) I'd like to acquire more knowledge about lambdas

Comment: There may be some different ways to organize the operations, but in the end you need the result of the merge/sum for apps before you can do the sorting so I think it will always entail (at least) two logical steps.

Comment: A basic question to clear few doubts, please specify what is `taskHandles` and what are those static imports that you've used. Would make the question much clearer.

Comment: taskHandles is a List<TaskHandle>, Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mapPayload is a function that extracts payload from each task and I have static imports of methods java.util.stream.Collector... of(), groupingBy(), toMap() and java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;

Comment: Ryan, so that is my question - where and how should I insert sorting step

Comment: You’ve already done it in your update as two separate steps (though really it’s much more than two since each chained method call on the stream is a separate step).

Comment: Ryan, and I’d like to know hot to do it in one stream

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the point of my earlier comment is that I don’t think that is possible. You need two passes through your data since you need the full result of the first stream before it is possible to do the sorting work of the second stream.

Comment: Maybe somehow in a merge function in a Collector?

Comment: Proper order is reversed order. I don’t create LinkedHashMap because on this step I merge values by duplicated keys from different maps. So first of all I should sum up values by duplicated keys and only after sort it

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you asked a Java question, but only provided some kind of JSON to describe your input. As far as recognizable, you’re calling `stream()` on some `taskHandles` of unknown type, map the elements by calling `this.mapPayload(…)`, to convert these element of unknown type to something other of unknown type, followed by a complex `collect` operation, which we are supposed to understand without any clue about the actual input. There might be a solution, but not when we have to do reverse engineering of your code first.

Comment: After I do mapPayload just return Map<String, Map<String, Long>>. So after this step I have a list of Maps

Comment: You mean, a stream of maps?

Comment: Yes, exactly. JSON represents this intermediate step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not avoid collecting the values into the map, before you can create the `LinkedHashMap` ordered by the resulting values, but you can specify the conversion step as *finisher* function of your custom collector:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> organizationApps = input.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collector.of(HashMap::new,
        (r, t) -> t.getValue().forEach((k, v) -> r.merge(k, v, Long::sum)),
        (r1, r2) -> {
            r2.forEach((v1, v2) -> r1.merge(v1, v2, Long::sum));
            return r1;
        },
        (Map<String, Long> m) -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                LinkedHashMap::new))
    )));
```

which would be equivalent to the following (Java 9+) code

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> organizationApps = input.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, collectingAndThen(flatMapping(
            t -> t.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
            toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::sum)),
        (Map<String, Long> m) -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                LinkedHashMap::new))
    )));
```

At the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) is a Java 8 compatible implementation of the `flatMapping` collector, but your custom collector does the job as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!